# the first fwrite works but not the second

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

I don't know why the first `fwrite()` for `customer`, works, but not the second `fwrite()` for the symbol of the message. My program wants to check if the customer and the symbol from the message already contained in the library`.dat`. Here is my piece of code :

```
typedef struct {
    char Name[50];
    int totalmsg;
    int totalword;
} Customer;

typedef struct {
    char symbol;
    char alphabet[20];
} Ssymbol;

void add_customer () {
    boolean found;
    int i;

    fp = fopen("customer.dat", "wb+"); 
    fread(&Customer_history, sizeof(TabInt), 102, fp);

    i = GetLastIdx(Customer_history);
    do {
        printf ("Please input customer's name: ");scanf("%s",&temp); 
        if (i == 0) {
            i++;
            SetName(&Customer_history,i,temp);
            SetMsg(&Customer_history,i,i);
            SetEff(&Customer_history,i);
            printf("Do you still wanna add another customer ?(Y/N)"); scanf("%s",&CC);
        }
        else {
            found = Search_name(Customer_history,temp);
            if (found == true) {
                printf("The name is already exist \n\n");
            }
            else {
                i++;
                SetName(&Customer_history,i,temp);
                    SetMsg(&Customer_history,i,i);
                    SetEff(&Customer_history,i);
            }
            printf("Do you still wanna add another customer ?(Y/N)"); scanf("%s",&CC);
        } 
    } while ((CC == 'y') || (CC =='Y'));
    fwrite(&Customer_history, sizeof(Customer), 102, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

void add_symbol() {

    char tempc;
    char tempalphabet[20];
    boolean found;
    int i;

    fp = fopen("library.dat","wb+");

    fread(&list_symbol, sizeof(Ssymbol), 52, fp);

    i = GetLastIdx2(list_symbol);

    do{
        printf("Please input new symbol:");
        scanf("%s", &tempc);

        printf("Please input the alphabet of the symbol:");
        scanf("%s", &tempalfabet);

        if (i==0){
            i++;
            SetSymbol(&list_symbol,i,tempc);
            SetAlphabet(&list_symbol,i,tempalphabet);
            printf("Do you want to add another symbol? (Y/N)");
            scanf("%s",&CC);
        }      
        else{
            found = Search_symbol(list_symbol, tempc);
            if (found==true){
                printf("Symbol is already exist \n\n");
            }
            else{
                i++;
                SetSymbol(&list_symbol,i,tempc);
                SetAlphabet(&list_symbol,i,tempalphabet);
                printf("Do you want to add another symbol? (Y/N)");
                scanf("%s",&CC);
            }            
        }
    }

    while((CC=='y') || (CC=='Y'));

    fwrite(&list_symbol, sizeof(Ssymbol),52, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: What are Customer_history and list_symbol declarations? Unless there is error code, fwrite can't just ignore anything on it's preference, it's all just bytes.

Comment: At a wild guess, the `fread` changes the file offset, so you're writing to a second record after the first. An `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)` just prior to the `fwrite` should address the issue.

Comment: This code is missing so many declarations and definitions that, aside from blatantly obvious errors (like `scanf()`ing a string into a single char, not checking a *single* library api call, etc.) anything you'll get is utter speculation. FFS post **compilable** code. Ex. the first line after an unchecked `fopen()` block-reads something the size of an undefined `TabInt` into a memory address of an undefined variable `Customer_history`. The next line calls an undefined `GetLastIdx()` and this mantra continues throughout the code. The only thing keeping this from being closed now is the bounty.

Comment: What @WhozCraig said is correct, without a complete version of your code, getting this error "fixed" is going to be guess work at best, impossible at worst. That said, I found about a dozen things you need to look at and verify. Check my answer for that. If you choose to update your code with the rest of the definitions that are missing and a sample of your .dat file, please ping me and I'll refine the answer for you.

Comment: -1 for placing a bounty on code that won't even compile

Answer (score 4):

If you are only expecting a single character here:

```
scanf("%s", &tempc);
```

then change it to:

```
scanf("%c", &tempc);
```

otherwise, you need to define tempc as an array (and don't use `&`).

Here also, since tou are passing an array, you should not use address-of (`&`):

```
printf("Please input the alphabet of the symbol:");
// scanf("%s", &tempalfabet); is wrong
scanf("%s", tempalfabet); // correct
```

Inspect all scanf calls in your code and fix them

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without a more "compile-able" version of your code... Here're some points for you:

A) `boolean` is not a type in C. You'll need something like:

```
#include <stdbool.h> // or some other header that defines bool
typedef bool boolean;
```

Failing that:

```
typedef int boolean;
#define false 0
#define true 1
```

B) `add_customer()` and `add_symbol()` using `fp` which is not defined. You need to define a `FILE * fp` for those operations.

C) The following (I assume to be) methods are not defined: `GetLastIdx()`, `SetName()`, `SetMsg()`, `SetEff()`, `Search_Name()`, `GetLastIdx2()`, `SetSymbol()`, `SetAlphabet()`, `Search_symbol()`

D) The following (I assume to be) global variables and data structers are not defined: `Customer_history`, `TabInt`, `temp`, `CC`, `list_symbol`, `tempalfabet`

Based on your problem description I assume you have this working, so these should all be defined. If you can provide a more complete, compile-able version of your code showing the problem, I could be of more help.

So based on what I have, here's some input:

1) You are reading into your `list_symbol`, this should be a pointer to a block of memory big enough for `52*sizeof(Ssymbol)`, this should be around 1092 bytes.

```
fread(&list_symbol, sizeof(Ssymbol), 52, fp);
```

Also note that if `list_symbol` is an array of `Ssymbol`s then your read code be screwed up by the fact that you have an array in your structure, `fread()` will read and fill your data *exactly* byte for byte. For example:

```
Ssymbol list_symbol[52];
FILE * fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
memset(list_symbol, 0, 52*sizeof(Ssymbol));
fread(list_symbol, sizeof(Ssymbol), 52, fp);
```

And let's says "test.txt" has in it:

```
C abcdefghijklmn
3 12345678
```

Then your `list_symbol` will look like:

```
list_symbol[0].symbol = 'C'
list_symbol[0].alphabet = ' abcdefghijklmn3 12' //note the newline and spaces fill it
list_symbol[1].symbol = '3'
list_symbol[1].alphabet = '45678'
```

And that might not be what you wanted to do. Make sure your data matches your structures!

2) Your one `scanf()` that you completely show is wrong:

```
char tempc;
...
scanf("%s", &tempc);
```

You want "%c" if you want a character, not "%s". I don't see the other declarations (see point D) above, however based on your prints and your usage I can tell you `tempalfabet` and `CC` are almost certainty wrong as well.

3) Your `scanf()`s are going to leave newline characters unless you consume them:

```
printf("Please input new symbol:");
scanf("%c\\n", &tempc);  // <-- escaped newline will do that for you
```

4) You open your files with "wb+". See [fopen() options](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) that's for writing and appending to a binary file. If you want a binary file to **read and write** you need: "ab+", if you want a text file "a+" will do.

5) You do not reset the file pointer:

```
fopen(file for reading, writing, and appending);
fread(stuff);
do c code;
fwrite(stuff);
```

This will result in what you have written being appended to the bottom of your file. *I don't know if that's what you wanted*. So this might not be a problem if you wanted to read a full `list_symbol` worth of data, then append a new set to the bottom of your file. I ***suspect*** that you wanted to overwrite what was in your file however... in which case you need to [fseek()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) back to the beginning, or you can simply close and open the file.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to *guess* the issue, since the entire code is not vailable..

Is it possible that the number of symbols is exceeding 52, and you are writing only first 52 symbols? So fwrite is indeed working, but it is not changing the data file. Try printf'ing i(=GetLastIdx2), to see if it is exceeding 52.

Also, instead of having array for list_symbols, I would recommend using a linked list & fread/fwrite, using a while loop, to read/write all the symbols in the data file.

Answer (score 0):

From the code logic, it want to read some data from file and then update it.

Then you should use "rb+" mode to open the file, instead of "wb+" which truncate the whole data. With "wb+" mode, the file data is truncated and the `fread()` should return 0, the whole do/while becomes invalid.

I don't know why the first `fwrite()` works, both of them should not.

In all, try `ab+` mode in `fopen()`, and don't forget to call `fseek()` with SEEK_SET to reset the file position indicator before calling `fwrite()`, it may resolve your problem.